# Laplace operator singularity at the poles

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, laplacian, singularity

I have the following mixed boundary value problem

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\Delta \tau(\theta) = -1, \quad 0\leq\theta <\theta_{\max}, \\
\tau(\theta_{\max}) = 0,  \\
\left. \dfrac{\partial \tau(\theta)}{\partial \theta} \right|_{\theta = 0} =0. 
\end{array}
$$
Where $\Delta$ is the laplace operator in spherical coordinates. This can easily be integrated. Namely $r = sin \theta$. Also note that there is no radial dependence and azimuthal symmetry

\begin{align*} 
  & \Delta \tau(r)=\frac{\sqrt{1-r^2}}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \Big( r \sqrt{1-r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \Big)  \tau = -1,  \Longleftrightarrow
  \frac{\partial \tau(r)}{\partial r} = \frac{1}{r} + \frac{C_1}{r \cdot \sqrt{1-r^2}},  \Longleftrightarrow\\
  &\tau(r) =  \log r + \frac{C_1}{2} \log \left( \frac{1-\sqrt{1-r^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-r^2}} \right) + C_2, \Longleftrightarrow \\    
  &\tau(\theta) = \log (\sin \theta) + \frac{C_1}{2} \log \left( \frac{1-\cos\theta}{1+\cos \theta}\right) + C_2.
\end{align*}

How can I deal with the singularity at $\theta = 0$? Physically, the solution for $\tau(\theta)$ must be finite even in $\theta = 0$

Mathematica gives the solution

$$
\tau(\theta) = \log(1+\cos\theta) -\log(1-\cos \theta_{\max})
$$

This solution can be "derived" by ignoring the singularities. No idea

Comment: Is there somehow no radial dependence at all?

Comment: The radius is fixed. There is no radial dependence. I will edit the question

Comment: Alright, well, provided that $\theta$ does not extend as far as $\pi$, you can kill the singularity at 0 by appropriate choice of $C_1$. Specifically it looks like you want $C_1=-1/2$. Does that work at $\pi$ as well? (I haven't checked)

Comment: Is you region of solution a `spherical cap'? If so, I do not think it is valid to place a BC at the *point* $\theta=0$. Your boundary data at $\theta=\theta_{\text{max}}$ encloses the solution region, and any further specifications make the problem ill posed.

Comment: The region of solution is a spherical cap from 0 to thetha_max

Comment: What I mean is that $d\tau(0)/d\theta:=0$ is a consequence of the smoothness of solutions to your PDE, not one that you have the freedom to implement.  To actually answer your question: expand your solution about $\theta=0$ to find

$
\tau\sim \ln(\theta-\frac{\theta^3}{6}+ \cdots)+\frac{C_1}{2}\ln(\frac{\theta^2}{2}-\cdots)-\frac{C_1}{2}\ln(2-\frac{\theta^2}{2}+\cdots)+C_2
$
Leading to

$
\tau \sim \ln(\theta)+C_1\ln(\theta)-C_1\ln(2)+C_2
$

For $\tau(0)$ to be finite, the singular part must vanish, so $C_1=-1$. Then $C_2$ is determined by your boundary data at $\theta_\text{max}$

Comment: Oh, Sal is right, it is $C_1=-1$ because there's the division by 2 already there. I implicitly aggregated $C_1/2$ into $C_1'$ in my mental algebra without even noticing.